# Не работает backspace в input при таком скрипте

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Проблема такая: есть скрипт на jQuery

```js
$("#captchaField").on("keypress keydown blur",function (event) { 
"use strict";
     $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[^\d].+/, ""));
      if ((event.which < 48 || event.which > 57)) {
        event.preventDefault();}
});
```

Он позволяет вводить только цифры в поле, но когда я его пытаюсь очистить нажав `backspace` или заменить его текущее значение выделив какой-то символ и пытаюсь заменить его другим (я может непонятно объясняю, но можно в `input` выделить символы и при нажатии на любую клавишу с символом значение `input`, которое вы выделили будет изменено на символ клавиши). С этим скриптом эти возможности урезаются. Помогите вернуть их обратно.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/1wshd8cL/

Comment: @splash58  Спасибо. То что надо.

Comment: @splash58 цифровая клаа справа не пашет, 96-105 добавить бы

Comment: смотрите здесь коды и добавлйте исключения на нужные - https://api.jquery.com/event.which/

Comment: @Jean-Claude  Ээххммм. Ну и фиг с ней, мы же не клерки чтоб ей пользоваться

Comment: @Jean-Claude  хотя если напишите keyCode для цифровой клавиатуры справа, то можно будет и её заставить работать

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно использовать `input` событие. И поправил регулярное выражение - оно разрешало один любой символ после цифр.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#captchaField').on('input', function(event) { 
    $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[^\d]+/, ''));
  }); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js">
<input type="text" id="captchaField"/>
```

Comment: буквы после цифр затирают поле

Comment: И ещё бесят стрелочки у input number справа.

Comment: @EugenEray, обновил код.

Comment: @AlexZhulin  Блин я с телефона не могу проверить :(